# Can Moderators See Edits Made to Answers Within 5 Minutes?

Tags: discussion, editing

Can moderators etc. can see edits made within 5 minutes?

I ask because I answered a question one minute after someone else but they quickly changed their answer to include information from mine. But since early edits are apparently not recorded it makes it look like I am to blame for duplicating their answer. This sort of thing could become very annoying if it happens again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they cannot. Edits within the grace period are the same as the original entry of the post...

Answer (score 6):

Just a little check...
THIS IS AN EARLY EDIT.

Timeline doesn't show an edit either: https://meta.superuser.com/posts/1323/timeline... Too bad :(